# download url is having null value when opening a google drive files from iPhone App

Tags: google-drive-api, xcode4.6

I am using google drive sdk for iOS app.User should be able to open a document from our App. I am trying to download the files from my Google drive using below code -

```
- (void)loadFileContent {

     UIAlertView *alert = [DrEditUtilities showLoadingMessageWithTitle:@"Loading file content" delegate:self];

GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =[self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:self.driveFile.downloadUrl];

[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

if (error == nil) {

  NSString* fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  self.textView.text = fileContent;

  self.originalContent = [fileContent copy];

} else {

  NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);

  [DrEditUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to load file" message:[error description] delegate:self];
}
}]; }
```

But when I try to download the Google docs files, download URL is having null value. please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get download URL for Google Docs file. They are just saved in the server and you cannot see its content directly. This is same for other products such as spreadsheet and presentation. Instead, you can get exportLinks. It will help you to get documents in various known formats such as .doc or .pdf

If you really want to have more control over Google Docs, you can use Google Apps Script's [Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#) class

Comment: Thank you for reply.I already tried export link but it's not working. I read your link but i did not found how do this is in "Objective C".If you know then can you please share it with me.

Comment: If you want to make consumer application, you can't use GAS. I would rather investigate why export link is not working and try to work on it. You can export the file, work on it, and upload it with request to convert it back to Docs file.

Comment: I used [self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:self.driveFile.alternateLink];now i am getting correct url but the fileContents in TextView are in json format. i tried to convert it but i am getting null value so textView displaying nothing.

Comment: @JunYoungGwak hi I am able to get DownloadUrl but i want exportLinks or link which can be used for streaming file from google drive. if u have any idea Plz Let me Know

Comment: How can you tell apart a Google file from a non-Google file?